# Search in Elasticsearch objects from non blocked user

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elaasticsearch we have 3 collections, users, products and blocked_users.

```
user[
{id: 1, first_name: “John”, last_name:“Snow”, …}
{id: 2, first_name: “Sarah”, last_name:“Connor”, …}
{id: 2, first_name: “Arnold”, last_name:“Schwarzenegger”, …}
]

products[
{id: 1, user_id: 3, title:“Apple”}
]

blocked_users[
{user_id: 2, blocked_user_id: 3} // this mean user with id 2 blocked user with id 3
]
```

I want to search products by title, but I don't want to show products of blocked users.

So, when user with id 1 search he will get a response with 1 product
when user with id 2 search 0 products is expected, because product user id is 3, but user with id 2 blocked this user

How should be query?

Comment: Please show your mappings. It's not clear what a collection is in your case.

Comment: @MartinSchulze I've edited

Comment: I think in your case, it is better to combine these 3 types into one type, so one big user type with an products nested array and a blocked user indicator.